# Safari 8 freezes while using canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari

I'm working on a [canvas experiment using blending modes and particles](http://codepen.io/isuttell/full/raxRaJ/) and I've run into a problem with Safari 8. The code works great in Chrome. In Firefox it's a bit slow but still functional. I've tested it in Safari 7 and the most recent version of the Mobile Safari which both work fine, however when I test it in Safari 8, the animation runs for a few cycles and then freezes the entire tab. I've tried greatly simplifying the animations, amount of particles, blending modes, et cetera, and I still haven't managed to track down what is causing the most recent version of Safari to freeze. Is there something Safari related that I'm missing?

```
var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
var HALF_PI = Math.PI / 2;

var isTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window;

function Canvas(options) {
  options = _.clone(options || {});
  this.options = _.defaults(options, this.options);

  this.el = this.options.el;
  this.ctx = this.el.getContext('2d');

  this.dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

  this.updateDimensions();
  window.addEventListener('resize', _.bind(this.updateDimensions, this), false);
  this.resetTarget();

  if(isTouch){
     // touch
     this.el.addEventListener('touchstart', this.touchMove.bind(this), false);
     this.el.addEventListener('touchmove', this.touchMove.bind(this), false);
  } else {
    // Mouse
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove.bind(this), false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseout', this.resetTarget.bind(this), false);
  }

  this.setupParticles();

  this.loop();
}

Canvas.prototype.updateDimensions = function() {
  this.width = this.el.width = _.result(this.options, 'width') * this.dpr;
  this.height = this.el.height = _.result(this.options, 'height') * this.dpr;
  this.el.style.width = _.result(this.options, 'width') + 'px';
  this.el.style.height = _.result(this.options, 'height') + 'px';
}

// Update the orb target
Canvas.prototype.mouseMove = function(event) {
  this.target = new Vector(event.clientX * this.dpr, event.clientY* this.dpr);
}

// Reset to center when we mouse out
Canvas.prototype.resetTarget = function() {
  this.target = new Vector(this.width / 2, this.height /2);
}

// Touch Event
Canvas.prototype.touchMove = function(event) {
  if(event.touches.length === 1) {  event.preventDefault(); }
    this.target = new Vector(event.touches[0].pageX * this.dpr, event.touches[0].pageY * this.dpr);
}

// Defaults
Canvas.prototype.options = {
  count: 20,
  speed: 0.5,
  width: 400,
  height: 400,
  size: 10,
  radius: 5,
  background: '29, 22, 52',
  maxDistance: 10000
}

Canvas.prototype.setupParticles = function() {
  this.particles = [];
  var index = -1;
  var between = PI2 / this.options.count;
  while(++index < this.options.count) {
    var x;
    var y;
    var angle;
    var max = Math.max(this.width, this.height);

    angle = (index + 1) * between;

    x = Math.cos(angle) * max;
    x += this.width / 2;

    y = Math.sin(angle) * max;
    y += this.height / 2;

    var particle = new Particle({
      x: x,
      y: y,
      radius: this.options.radius,
      size: this.options.size,
      angle: angle,
      color: this.options.color
    });

    this.particles.push(particle);
  }
}

Canvas.prototype.findClosest = function() {
  var index = -1;
  var pointsLength = this.particles.length;

  while(++index < pointsLength) {
    var closestIndex = -1;
    this.particles[index].closest = [];

    while(++closestIndex < pointsLength) {
      var closest = this.particles[closestIndex];
      var distance = this.particles[index].position.distanceTo(closest.position);
      if(distance < this.options.maxDistance) {
        var vector = new Vector(closest.position.x, closest.position.y);
        vector.opacity = 1 - (distance / this.options.maxDistance);
        vector.distance = distance;
        this.particles[index].closest.push(vector);
      }
    }
  }
}

Canvas.prototype.loop = function() {
  if(isTouch) {
      this.ghost();
  } else {
      this.ghostGradient();
  }    
  if(this.options.maxDistance > 0) {
      this.findClosest();
  }    
  this.draw();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(_.bind(this.loop, this));
}

Canvas.prototype.clear = function() {
  this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0 , this.width, this.height);
}

Canvas.prototype.ghost = function() {
  this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  this.ctx.rect(0, 0 , this.width, this.height);
  if(typeof this.options.background === 'string') {
      this.ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + this.options.background + ")";
  } else  {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + this.options.background[0] + ")";
  }

  this.ctx.fill();
}

Canvas.prototype.ghostGradient = function() {
  var gradient;

  if(typeof this.options.background === 'string') {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + this.options.background + ')';   
  } else {
        var gradient = this.ctx.createRadialGradient(this.width/2, this.height/2, 0, this.width/2, this.height/2, Math.max(this.width, this.height)/2);

    var length = this.options.background.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
      gradient.addColorStop((i+1) / length, 'rgb(' + this.options.background[i] + ')');
    }
    this.ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
  }

  this.ctx.globalOpacity = 0.1;
  this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "darken";
  this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0 , this.width, this.height);
}

// Draw
Canvas.prototype.draw = function() {
  var index = -1;
  var length = this.particles.length;
  while(++index < length) {
    var point = this.particles[index];
    var color = point.color || this.options.color;
    point.update(this.target, index);

    this.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
    this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighten";
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + color + ')';
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(point.position.x, point.position.y, point.size, PI2, false);
    this.ctx.closePath();
    this.ctx.fill();

    if(this.options.maxDistance > 0) {
        this.drawLines(point, color);
    }
  }  
}

// Draw connecting lines
Canvas.prototype.drawLines = function (point, color) {
  color = color || this.options.color;
  var index = -1;
  var length = point.closest.length;
  this.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
  this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "screen";
  this.ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  while(++index < length) {
    this.ctx.lineWidth = (point.size * 2) *  point.closest[index].opacity;
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(' + color + ', ' + point.closest[index].opacity + ')';
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.moveTo(point.position.x, point.position.y);
    this.ctx.lineTo(point.closest[index].x, point.closest[index].y);
    this.ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function Particle(options) {
  options = _.clone(options || {});
  this.options = _.defaults(options, this.options);

  this.position = this.shift = new Vector(this.options.x, this.options.y);

  this.speed = this.options.speed || 0.01 + Math.random() * 0.04;

  this.angle = this.options.angle || 0;

  // Randomize color a little  
  if(this.options.color) {
    var color = this.options.color.split(',');
      var colorIndex = -1;
    while(++colorIndex < 3) {      
      color[colorIndex] = Math.round(parseInt(color[colorIndex], 10) + (Math.random()*100)-50);

      // Clamp
      color[colorIndex] = Math.min(color[colorIndex], 255);
      color[colorIndex] = Math.max(color[colorIndex], 0);
    }
    this.color = color.join(', ');
  } 

  // Size
  this.options.size = this.options.size || 7;
  this.size = 1 + Math.random() * this.options.size;
  this.targetSize = this.options.targetSize || this.options.size;

  this.orbit = this.options.radius * 0.5 + (this.options.radius * 0.5 * Math.random());
}

Particle.prototype.update = function(target, index) {
  this.angle += this.speed;

  this.shift.x += (target.x - this.shift.x) * this.speed;
  this.shift.y += (target.y - this.shift.y) * this.speed;

  this.position.x = this.shift.x + Math.cos(index + this.angle) * this.orbit;
  this.position.y = this.shift.y + Math.sin(index + this.angle) * this.orbit;

  this.size += (this.targetSize - this.size) * 0.03;

  if(Math.round(this.size) === Math.round(this.targetSize)) {
    this.targetSize = 1 + Math.random() * this.options.size;
  }
}

function Vector(x, y) {
  this.x = x || 0;
  this.y = y || 0;
}

Vector.prototype.distanceTo = function(vector, abs) {
  var distance = Math.pow(this.x - vector.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.y - vector.y, 2);
  return abs || false ? Math.abs(distance) : distance;
};

// Create instance
new Canvas({
  el: document.getElementById('canvas'),

  count: 25,
  speed: 0.3,
  radius: 6,
  width: function() { return window.innerWidth; },
  height: function() { return window.innerHeight; },
  size: 15,
  color: '30, 180, 1',
  maxDistance: 10000,
  background: ['1, 62, 66', '1, 40, 60']
});
```

The code can also be found on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/isuttell/pen/raxRaJ/).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an argument in `ctx.arc`

```
this.ctx.arc(point.position.x, point.position.y, point.size, PI2, false);
```

Should be :

```
this.ctx.arc(point.position.x, point.position.y, point.size, 0, PI2, false);
```

I'm raising a bug with Safari now, because this should not cause the browser to crash.